# How do these toroidal reflectors form an image in two dimensions?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, imaging

A torus has a major and minor radius, which means a symmetric section of one will have different focal lengths in its focal plane, or [astigmatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astigmatism_(optical_systems)). If it's from the "outside" of the torus (where you'd bite a donut or bagel) they will have the same sign (first photo), but if it's  "inside" of the torus (part of the hole) then they have opposite sign (second photo).

But these two multi-feed satellite dish antennas use a toroidal surface either by itself or in conjunction with another reflector to focus plane waves incident from different directions to different microwave feeds/amplifiers.

**Question:** Is there a simple way to understand, at least to first order, how these toroidal mirrors form an imaging system, focusing both horizontally and vertically in the same plane, and (apparently) doing this for such a wide range of incident angles?

[image]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Antenne-toroidale.jpg)

[image]

> The satellite antenna at Layer3 TV’s super headend facility in Denver, Colorado.LAYER3 TV [Source](https://www.wired.com/2016/04/layer3-tv/)

Comment: why should these form "an imaging system", they just focus the signal?

Comment: @ManudeHanoi "focus" and "image" usually go together. I'm pretty sure that in this application the collection system must form a coherent image,not simply concentrate radiation incoherently (as in a solar collector). I believe (though can't yet prove) that the system will not be some [non-imaging optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonimaging_optics) implementation. Many people don't associate the word "imaging" with microwave optics, and the resulting image may not be diffraction limited and have substantial aberration, but I think it will turn out to be okay to call these systems "imaging"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focal point depends on the direction of incoming light.
Such system would help finding the location of the source (radar).

> Torus antennas are used to allow a plurality of main beam directions
>   simultaneously using only one large stationary reflector.

[...]

> In order to reduce this aberration losses a second reflector can be
>   added similar to a Cassegrain antenna. With help of this socondary
>   reflector the phase differences can be compensated at the boundaries
>   of footprints on the primary reflector

http://www.radartutorial.eu/06.antennas/Torus%20Antenna.en.html

Comment: This is an interesting link, thanks, I will give it a thorough read. I found a [non-paywalled](http://inside.mines.edu/~rhaupt/journals/APS%20MAG%20Apr%202015.pdf) copy of [reference 1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7094261) but it does not directly cover this geometry. There may be some mathematical analysis out there somewhere though. In any event this is a very helpful answer, thank you!